# trouble creating virtual environment for python 3 in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, python-venv

I want to create a virtualenv in Windows 10 for python 3.7

I'm trying to follow the instruction from [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

So first I entered the command

```
PS T:\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
```

it did create directories and files into that path

then according to the documentation, using PowerShell I entered:

```
PS T:\path\to\myenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

but I got the following:

```
 The term
'T:\path\to\myenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ T:\path\to\myenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (T:\path\to\myenv...ts\Activate.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I missing

Comment: your virtualenv is on c drive - `c:\path\to\myenv`

Answer (score 0):

you should replace

```
path\to\myenv
```

to your actual path
so as said in docs

```
C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

for example it should be something like

```
C:\>MyProjectsFolder\first_project\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

the other workaround is to manually change directories to Scripts folder and then run

```
Activate.ps1
```

if it didnt solve your problem please specify your project folder and structure

Comment: thank you for your answer @MMoallemi99. According to the doc, it says 1. On Windows, invoke the venv command as follows: `c:\>c:\Python35\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv` and then 2. "Once a virtual environment has been created, it can be “activated” using a script in the virtual environment’s binary directory. The invocation of the script is platform-specific (<venv> must be replaced by the path of the directory containing the virtual environment):". So to which path structure shall I substitute `c:\path\to\myenv` in 1?

Comment: to the path that your project actually exist in e.g.
c:\PycharmProjects\mywebsite\venv
please post your actual project's path so i can help you

Comment: ok thank you @MMoallemi99. I Don't have a project yet, I'm just trying to create a virtual environment first and then only I would install libraries. So the exact steps I did in PowerShell are the Following. 1. I entered the Following: `PS T:\> python -m venv project_env`. It created files and directories. 2. I then tried both `PS T:\> project_env\activate.bat` and `PS T:\> project_env\activate.ps1` but got the message: `project_env\activate.ps1 : The module 'project_env' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
project_env'.
At line:1 char:1
+ project_env\activate.ps1`

Comment: Where it says C:\path\to\the\environment

it's not literally "C:\path\to\the\environment". It is telling *you* to replace that part with the path to *your* environment. 

Like if it says "write your name here", you don't write "Your Name here", you write "ecjb"